# JQuery, DataTables... Re-draw/update cells or tr's after multidelete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatables with the option to multidelete using checkboxes (it works perfectly) and the table re-draws dynamically (I don't want to reload the page, I need to do it without refreshing), removing the rows I deleted.
[image]

In the database, I have a column named Order (image's Posición) containing the order of the rows in the database, and it updates when I delete registers.

What I need to do is, visually, when I delete 1 or more rows in my Datatables, get the cells updated or re-drawn, so the order (Posición in the image) re-drawns dynamically (it updates correctly in the database).

But what happens now is that I don't know how to do that, and those cells stay with the "old" Order/Posición values (I repeat that it works just fine in the database):
[image]

I need that 5 and 7 values appear with the updated and real values: 4 and 5.

I have this code inside the delete button event and it updates just the next cell:

```
var celda_posicion = $(this).closest('tr').next().children(':eq(1)');
var dato_posicion = $(this).closest('tr').next().children(':eq(1)').text();

dato_posicion = parseInt(dato_posicion) - 1;

table.cell(celda_posicion).data(dato_posicion);
```

### DATATABLES trying "ajax": "data.json":

```
var table = $('#tabla_diccionarios').DataTable( {
   "ajax": "data.json",
   "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
   "language": "json",
   "lengthMenu": [[-1, 10, 25, 50], ["Todos", 10, 25, 50]],
   "language": {
       "lengthMenu": "Mostrar registros _MENU_ ",
       "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados.",
       "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros.",
       "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
       "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
       "paginate": {
           "previous": "Anterior",
           "next": "Siguiente",
       },
       "search": "Buscar: ",
   }
});
```

This gives me this errors:
- error 404 data.json not found
- DataTables warning: table id=tabla_diccionarios - Invalid JSON response

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );
```

after delete event, you can use
`table.ajax.reload();`

Comment: It gives me this error: DataTables warning: table id=tabla_diccionarios - Invalid JSON response  ///  Gonna edit my question with the DataTables so you can see it.

Comment: What is the difference between  `"ajax": "data.json"` and `ajax: "data.json"` ...?

Comment: You need tweak data.json (probably you a using api url or something). Once you delete call table.ajax.reload

Comment: @SanK what do you mean with "tweak data.json"? I'm very newbie and don't understand some things